# Redirect to another page on page load but only after a check is made

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a feature whereby a user can only view a job that they're given if they've agreed to the HIPAA guidelines. If they have already agreed, the job page will load as normal onclick, but if not, they should be redirected to the guidelines page.

I have tried a page redirect, but that gives me a 404 error.  I have my program (PHP) checking a field in the database; if it's 1 then they have agreed and the job page should load as normal.  If it is 0 then they should be redirected to the HIPAA page.  I am calling a function on checking the database field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hipaa() {
    var referringUrl = window.location.href;
    window.location.href = 'user/hipaa';
}
</script>
```

And

```
if ($result[0]->hipaa == 0) {
        $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  // current page so user can return
        hipaa(); // EDIT: removed this line
        //Added these lines:
        $urlNew = '/user/guidelines';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV-REFRESH CONTENT = "1; ' . $urlNew . '">';
    }
```

The function gets called but the window.location.href gives me a 404 error. Any help would be much appreciated. I am a relative beginner in JavaScript.

EDIT: I updated my code to try and do it through PHP and I don't get an error now, but it doesn't redirect, it just stays on the same page.

Comment: Well first you have to decide whether you want to do that on the PHP or JavaScript side...

Comment: Whatever works. Granted that I have been looking at this for a while, so I am probably not thinking clearly. How would I do that in PHP?

Comment: A 404 error means that you've directed the user to a page that doesn't exist. Compare the URL of the 404 to the URL you're expecting. There's not much we can do here to resolve a 404 if we don't know your expected vs actual URL.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: Okay, I tried something like this in my code: 
    $urlNew = '/user/guidelines';
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV-REFRESH CONTENT = "1; ' . $urlNew . '">';  and I don't get an error now, but it's still not working.

Comment: Should be: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">` - although, this is discouraged by the W3C. Use `header()` as mentioned

Comment: To redirect with PHP, just call `header("Location: user/hipaa"); die();` Or you check the syntax of `http-equiv`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Examples and fix your code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. The page is a PHP page that's only a portion of the page.  The headers are in another file and are called on many different pages, so I can't put a header redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JavaScript and after playing around for a bit, got it to work. My code is:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "../guidelines";</script>';
```

Thank you to all who took the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Your META tag should look like this....

```
<?php

$urlNew = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988586/redirect-to-another-page-on-page-load-but-only-after-a-check-is-made';

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=\'' . $urlNew . '\'" />'; 

?>
```

But if you look at the W3C standard, even way back to (3.2) pre-97, it states that redirects should always "when possible" be issued server-side or by giving the visitor a link that is directly clickable.

Comment: Thank you, @Stephanie, for your reply. As I said above, I am working on a portion of a page, so I can't put something in the header as it is called by several other files.